# even or odd number using methods in java

Tags: java

java code to find even or odd number using methods. please help me i am getting below error..
[compiler output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmWcY.png)

my code is

```
class evenodd{
public static int evenodd(int num) {
    if(num%2==0){
        System.out.println("true");
    }
    else
        { System.out.println("false");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int evenodd=evenodd(9);
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see the image, can you please write your error.

Comment: please post your codes with correct format.

Comment: One of the three right-braces at the end needs to move to just in front of `public static void main...`

Comment: I believe that in a java class if you have a single static method the class should be declared static too.

Comment: You need to specify the error you're getting and the result of your test.

Comment: Your evenodd method not returning anything. Then why you make return type as int..?

Comment: @ZiMtyth That is not true, class which contains static method doesn't need to be declared static itself. Avoid posting believes, try posting what you *know* for sure (so test things before you write about them).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int evenodd(int num) {
    if(num%2==0){
        System.out.println("true");
    }
    else
        { System.out.println("false");
}
```

This Method is missing the return statement. You wrote the method as

```
static int
```

But you didn't write any return statement. Instead you are only printing.

try this code:

```
class evenodd{
    public static boolean evenodd(int num) {
            if(num%2==0){
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         boolean isEven=evenodd(9); 
          System.out.println(isEven);
    }
}
```